# How any is special? Type 'Node' cannot be converted to type 'ChildNode'

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, webpack

I have this:

```
const node = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer;
(node as ChildNode).replaceWith(...nodes)
```

The above throws an error during build time:

> Type 'Node' cannot be converted to type 'ChildNode'
>
> Property 'remove' is missing in type 'Node'

But if I:

```
(node as any).replaceWith(...nodes)
```

It compiles well. Can anyone explain?

EDIT:

Answer from ritaj which gets upvoted **does not solve my issue**

Comment: Those are the basics of Typescript interfaces : `any` means that you have no interface (so your variable doesn't have to follow any signature), while a `Node` and a `ChildNode` do not have the same signature (apparently `remove` is only on `ChildNode`s and not on `Node`s)

Comment: Ok,  i just wonder how this worked for other developer who wrote this...

Comment: Well first you would have to find a developer who wrote this :)

Comment: You shouldn't blindly cast types. Rather narrow the type with type guards. What happens when `const node` is NOT `ChildNode`? You will get a runtime error.

Comment: @ritaj, typeguarding didnt worked out on this. If you provide a working ex, i would consider as a valid naswer :))

Comment: @ritaj there's no runtime error for types. Only for methods that do not exist.

Comment: @Maryannah Exactly what I've said. `replaceWith` doesn't exist on `node: Node` and it will be a runtime error.

Comment: @ritaj you said `What happens when const node is NOT ChildNode? You will get a runtime error` : by that reasoning, what happens if `node` has the `replaceWith` function and is still of type `childNode`? You get no runtime error. So no, you didn't say that (but you probably meant it), I just wanted to be sure !

Comment: But `node: Node` which is NOT `node: ChildNode` doesn't have `replaceWith`, so it will be runtime error.

Comment: Could you provide your `ChildNode` class/interface?

Comment: @youri its Typescripts interface `ChildNode extends Node` and has those four methods defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a type guard:

```
function isChildNode(node: Node): node is ChildNode {
    // Might want some other property checks as well
    return 'replaceWith' in node;
}
```

And guard the type:

```
const node: Node = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer;

if (isChildNode(node)) {
    node.replaceWith();
}
```

Comment: it returns this error - **A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
  Type 'ChildNode' is not assignable to type 'Node'.
    Property 'baseURI' is missing in type 'ChildNode'.**

Comment: That's impossible. `ChildNode` extends `Node` so it has all of its properties. You are using a wrong `ChildNode` interface, I'm guessing.

Comment: What is your ChildNode interface? Typescript DOM lib already has `export interface ChildNode extends Node`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195699/discussion-between-ritaj-and-bigint).